# How to calculate the volume of a pyramid using its end points in an orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, volume

The base of a pyramid is a rectangle with corners in $(1, 0, 2), (2, 1, 0), (0, 1, 2)$ and $(0,0,3)$. The top has the coordinates $(7, 3, 5)$. Calculate the volume of the pyramid. The coordinates are set in an orthonormal basis.

I am thinking that I first calculate three vectors that make up three sides of the pyramid, from one starting point, like so:

$u= (7, 3, 5)-(0, 0, 3) = (7, 3, 2)$

$v = (0, 1, 2) - (0, 0, 3) = (0, 1, -1)$

$w = (2, 1, 0) - (0, 0, 3) = (2, 1, -3)$

after that I calculate $\det A$, where $u,v$ and $w$ are column matrices. $\det A = 24$.
Because it is a pyramid and not a parallelepiped, I need to divide it. The formula for a pyramid is $\frac{\text{base}\cdot\text{height}}{3}$, right? So the volume according to my calculations would be $8vu$, but that is inaccurate, because the right answer is $6vu$. Therefore, I could adjust my answer to divide $\det A$ by $4$, but I don't understand why I would do that and I suspect it would be a faulty procedure. Would anybody care to explain what it is I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you are assuming that the determinant you calculated should be equal to "base*height". Why should that be the case?

Comment: Note that with your calculation method, choosing a different starting point yields a different answer, which should not be the case if we're computing the volume of the same pyramid

Comment: Also, something to be wrong with the "rectangle".  The positions of the corners relative to $(0,0,3)$ are $(2,1,-3),(0,1,-1),(1,0,-1)$. Because adjacent sides of a rectangle are perpendicular, two of these vectors should have a dot-product of $0$.